# Подправить регулярное выражение

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Не слишком силен в регулярках, прошу помощи, не добавляется товар, есть регулярка которая проверяет имя товара.

```
var $product_name_rules    = '\.\:\-_ a-z0-9а-яА-Я()-,.!&';
```

У меня в имение товара есть ковычки, как добавить в регулярку ковычки? "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var $product_name_rules    = '\"\.\:\-_ a-z0-9а-яА-Я()-,.!&';
```

А еще лучше так:

```
var $product_name_rules    = '\"\.\:\-_ a-z0-9а-яА-ЯЁё()-,.!&';
```

чтобы **ё** не терялась (она обычно не входит в диапазон а-я).

Comment: То что доктор прописал, спасибо, еще в дополнении вот эти ковычки поставил »